# the local orientation changes when i go into pose-mode, whats going on and how do i stop it?

Tags: armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

[image]

Resetting rotation with alt+R does nothing. I have deleted all keyframes and animation from the project, reset rotation and roll where ever I could find it. It affects both the toes, but only the toes. How can i change the rotation of the local rotation axis in edit and pose mode without changing the zero-pose or ruining my model?

Answer (score 0):

Separate bones don't really have local rotation in Edit mode. What you see, when you tab to edit mode of a rig is the local position of whole rig.Separate bones have local position only in Pose mode, so everything is as it should and you don't need to worry about this difference.
So if you want local position of the rig to match global coordinates, rotate the rig in object mode.